# AS3 - why am I getting this error "Access of undefined property minge"?

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-errors

I have this short code:

```
        public function ball() 
        {

            minge.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getBack);
        }

        private function getBack()
        {
        trace("test");  
        }
```

This error when I run:

```
Line 15 1120: Access of undefined property minge.
```

I do not understand why this error occurs ... I put a picture to see more clearly.

[image: Screenshot]

`minge` is an instance ... is an Assets

Can you tell me please what to do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Also look at this image for clarification:
[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Most likely you're class file isn't properly linked.   Please share how the class code you've shared relates to your .fla and screenshot

Comment: look at this image below http://i61.tinypic.com/14dk5eq.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The image link isn't working but my guess here is you do not have a named instance of minge on the stage. It can't just be in the library you have to either drag one onto the stage and give it the name minge in the properties or call it out from code and attach it to the stage. Also update your mouse event handler like this:

```
function getBack(event:MouseEvent):void
{
        trace("test");  
}
minge.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getBack, false, 0, true);
```

Also note that because your event is being attached inside of function ball you would have to call that function first before your event will be attached to that movie clip.

Edit: change your code on your actions layer to the code above. Make sure you have an instance of minge on the stage.

Comment: I just gave my name object "minge" in Adobe Flash

Comment: All you're doing is outputting "test" in the trace window. Have you looked to make sure it's not there? Don't just name it minge, try the code I added in my answer. When you do a trace on something it only outputs in the trace window, it does not pop up like a javascript alert. Also make sure the code above in on the stage (click in an empty key frame and add it to the actions pane).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the instance name `minge`.

The problem is that you give the instance name to the object that is an instance of the class itself. Even if it worked, it would be bad code, because the class would only work for this single instance with this specific instance name.

An instance name is only necessary if you want to reference an object from somewhere else. But the class you associate with the object is a representation of the object. You are not "somewhere else", but already in/on the object when you are in the class.

So when you write code in a class that is associated with an object, your point of view is from the object.

You as a person would always refer to yourself as "I", you would (usually) not refer to yourself with the name your parents gave you or a nickname that your friends use to identify you.

That being said: in the class for the ball, the ball is "I". The keyword equivalent to "I" or "myself" in As3 is `this`, so if you change your code like so, it should work:

```
    public function ball() 
    {
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getBack); // this line changed
    }

    private function getBack()
    {
        trace("test");  
    }
```

As a class is always written in the perspective of an object it is associated to, the `this` is actually optional. That means if you call a method without explicitly referencing an object, it will be called on `this` by default. The above code simplifies to the following:

```
    public function ball() 
    {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getBack); // this line changed again
    }

    private function getBack()
    {
        trace("test");  
    }
```

### conclusion

1. Methods are called on objects. Objects are accessed with references. instance name are one kind of references. However, a class is always written in the "I" perspective of an instance of it (but not a particular one). that's why an explicit instance name does not work. that's why you need to use `this`, to refer to the instance of a class.
2. `this` can be omitted in classes, because `this` is the default scope (so to speak)